WinRM cannot process the request in a remote powershell scripting
I am try to run this script remotely to know what is connecting in the usb port for more than 1000 servers with Windows 2022 Server, but it dosnt work. I am having this error WinRM cannot process the request error code 0x80090311, is important to let you know that localy works good.
this is the Script in PowerShell
function usbCheck {
    param (
        [string]$archivoSalida,
        [string]$hostList
    )
    #toma la lista de Servidores del path $hostList
    $servidores = Get-Content $hostList

    #solicita las Credenciales
    #$credenciales = Get-Credential
    foreach($servidor in $servidores){
            #Por cada servidor en la lista usara 
            $dispositivosUSB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servidor -Credential "administrator" -ScriptBlock{
            Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "HID UPS Battery"}
        }
        foreach($dispositivo in $dispositivosUSB){
            $dispositivoInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
                "HostName" = $servidor
                "Dispositivo" = $dispositivo.DeviceID
                "Descripcion" = $dispositivo.Description
                "Fabricante" = $dispositivo.Manufacturer
            }
            $dispositivoInfo | Export-Csv -Path $archivoSalida -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
        }
    }
}

usbCheck -archivoSalida "C:\Scripts\SAI_USB\usbLog.txt" -hostList "C:\Scripts\SAI_USB\hostList.txt".

Please format your post properly.

Error 0x80090311 means: "No authority could be contacted for authentication." On a general note: There's an about_Remote_Troubleshooting help topic.

I check this but now I can run the script into the servers within the same subnet but not in other servers within the domain but not in the same subnet.

Is this part of your script correct: -Credential "administrator"? The way it's written would prompt for credentials for each server. If you entered the wrong domain in your credential, like wrong\username, then you will get error 0x80090311 just like this.

@JorgeRomero the issue in your comment sounds like a network problem. Like if powershell is unable to reach a domain controller when connecting to those servers. Are you sure they're in the same domain?

@Cpt.Whale i am connecting local to the host localhost\administrator, i am try to connect for test to 3 servers, so Server1 and Server 2 are in  the same subnet ej. 10.1.1.2, 10.1.1.3, I can connect and run the script OK, but server3 is in diferent subnet 10.1.2.1 in this the script dont run for WinRM cannor complete the operation

[server3] Connecting to remote server Server3 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the
specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and

allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (ES02001RHS01:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken

Prepare for the future. Get-WmiObject is not available in PowerShell Core 7+. Use Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PnPEntity. Yes, it works on Windows PowerShell 5.1.
